# How can I retrieve the raw Json that is returned by AWS Rekognition?

Tags: c#, .net, json, aws-sdk, amazon-rekognition

For a comparison task I want to save all data returned by AWS Rekognition in .NET, in this case by DetectFaces, as json for later extraction.
How can I get the raw json? The .NET SDK does not offer any methods. I tried to serialize the face details without success.

```
[...]
AmazonRekognitionClient rekognitionClient = new AmazonRekognitionClient(destination::Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);

DetectFacesRequest detectFacesRequest = new DetectFacesRequest()
   {
       Image = awsImage,
       Attributes = new List<String>() { "ALL" }
   };

   try
   {
       DetectFacesResponse detectFacesResponse = rekognitionClient.DetectFaces(detectFacesRequest);
       List<FaceDetail> details = detectFacesResponse.FaceDetails;
   }catch {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the type of `details` is a `List<FaceDetail>` (not `FaceDetails`), which might be what's causing you issues here.

You should have no problem serializing that (using Json.NET) with:

```
...
var detectFacesResponse = rekognitionClient.DetectFaces(detectFacesRequest);
var details = detectFacesResponse.FaceDetails;

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(details);
```

Comment: Of course the List, never change code in the Stack Overflow editor without checking. I edited the answer. Thank you, the JsonConvert worked!